# Update a postgres table in SSIS

Tags: postgresql, ssis, oledb, oledbcommand

I am quite new to this:

My destination is a postgres table, and I want to update two fields (col1, col2) base on a column value from another sql server table (when postgres_table.a = sqlserver_table.b).

I know this could be easily realized by using OLEDB Command,  however, since my destination table is a postgres table that I used ODBC to connect, the OLEDB Command won't work for this case.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but how about using Foreach loop and Execute SQL task?

So first you read in the values to an object variable (use the Execute SQL -tas for this). Then use that variable as the source for Foreach loop and use another Execute SQL -task inside the loop to send an update to Postgres with correct values.